# Riemann hypothesis and zero of Mellin transform of eigenfunction of Schrödinger equation

Tags: fourier-analysis, quantum-mechanics, riemann-hypothesis

The paper [1] shows that the eigenfunction of the Schrödinger equation
$$
\left(x^2-\frac{1}{4\pi}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\right)f_n=\frac{2n+1}{2\pi}f_n
$$
satisfies the same functional equation as the Riemann zeta function does, and all the zeros of its 1 transform lie on the critical line $\operatorname{Re}(s)=\frac{1}{2}$.
On the other hand, it's also known (see [2]) that the Rieman zeta function can be considered as a Mellin transform of an eigenfunction of the Schrödinger equation in terms of $p$-adic, adelic quantum mechanics.

Can we get any result in this direction?

**References**

[1] Daniel Bump, Kwok-Kwong Choi, Pär Kurlberg, Jeffrey Vaaler, "A local Riemann hypothesis. I.", Mathematische Zeitschrift 233, No. 1, 1-19 (2000), [DOI:10.1007/PL00004786](https://doi.org/10.1007/PL00004786), [MR1738342](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1738342), [Zbl 0991.11022](https://zbmath.org/0991.11022).

[2] Branko Dragovich, "[Adelic harmonic oscillator](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0404160)", International Journal of Modern Physics A 10, No. 16, 2349-2365 (1995), [MR1334476](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1334476), [Zbl 1044.81585](https://zbmath.org/1044.81585).

Comment: What kind of result do you have in mind?

Comment: Distribution of zero of rieman zeta function.

Comment: Both papers are roughly 20 years old. If "we" have gotten any result from them about the zeros of zeta, I expect you could find it by searching for papers that cite both the Bump and Dragovich papers.